# How can I update npm, node version on Windows?

Tags: node.js, angular, windows, npm, package-managers

I am working on a finance project but now we start a new one here node version issue is getting, how to prevent this issue

Comment: [Download latest node.js version](https://nodejs.org/) | Update npm by running `npm install -g npm`

Answer (score 3):

You need to install new version on your machine go to [this](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) website and install whatever version you needed.

You can refer this as well
[Update Npm on windows](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade)

Run PowerShell as Administrator

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force 
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade 
npm-windows-upgrade
```

Note: Do not run `npm i -g npm`. Instead use `npm-windows-upgrade` to update npm going forward. Also if you run the NodeJS installer, it will replace the node version.

Answer (score 0):

you should try

https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

As you can manage node versions seamlessly with nvm